# Set child's Visible=false but keep AutoScrollbars of parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Let's say you have a `Panel1`, with a `Panel2` on it, partially out of `Panel1`'s bounds so Scrollbars appear on `Panel1`.

How can you make `Panel2` invisible, while keeping `Panel1`'s Scrollbars as they were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it yourself then:

```
panel1.AutoScroll = false;
panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(panel2.Right, panel2.Bottom);
```

Comment: It seems that the first line is not needed.

Comment: @ispiro I was just being explicit.  :-)